# How do I change my Stack Exchange password?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, user-accounts, password

How do I change my password?

I have a Stack Exchange account but can't seem to find the option to change my password.

Comment: clicking on "change password" simply redirects to the homepage. April fools!?

Comment: no, SE keeps changing the way to change password without ever telling anything, for their own internal reasons. People keep guessing and finding ways though, try one of the six answers below and you might be able to actually change the password. (And yes, it's a perfect example of what became of SE - company that doesn't care a bit for its users.)

Comment: What a mess... I thought for sure I was just tired when I couldn't figure out how to change my password. Then I ended up here from google. How on earth is this not made easily discoverable from the UI of any stack exchange site? This is a usability nightmare...

Comment: And then to top it off, I have two "logins", both for the same email/password combo - one listed under my email, and the other as "Stack Exchange". Maybe this somehow makes sense architecturally or something b/c of the openid backend, but blech.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I'm assuming "I have a Stack Exchange account" means you have a Stack Exchange ID.

Go to 'My logins' on your profile page; you can navigate directly to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current or, if you're already on your user page, click "Edit Profile & Settings", then "My Logins". Then you should see a **change password** link next to your Stack Exchange login:

[image: change password link on my logins]

Alternately, go to https://openid.stackexchange.com/ and login. At the top you'll see a "change password" tab:

[image]

If your OpenID provider is somewhere else then as ChrisF commented, the process varies

Comment: It looks as if the site is down openid.stackexchange. Am I the only one who is seeing problems ?

Comment: Found out the solution from huha's answer

Comment: Why does the passworts have to contain upper letters? From a cryptografic perspective it shrinks the possible key space!

Comment: @velop That's kind of the point, it prohibits keys that are easily brute-forced. From a cryptographic perspective all restrictions "shrink the keyspace", but that doesn't mean they should let your password be "password"

Comment: @MichaelMrozek True when I think about, it shifts the probability from one peculiarity to different ones like Password, PassWord, PaSsWoRd, so in reality it spreads the choosen passwords more equally over the shrunken keyspace.

Comment: My `My Logins` space only presents: `Log in or sign up on any Stack Exchange site using these accounts` and `add more logins…`. I don't see any `Email` type of login. I would like to change my password.

Comment: For the record, I went to the SE page and found the page you specified, but the "(change password)" links by any of the IDs were not there at all.  At the OpenID, the emails I use for SE are not recognized.

Comment: This is the dumbest workflow I have ever seen for any website. For one of the most popular web properties this is incredibly hard to find. Why is it so hard to just change my password?

Comment: @PlastyGrove Because Stack Exchange supports OpenID, so you can have multiple logins and in most cases those logins aren't controlled by SE at all, so they have nothing to do with changing your password. For an SE login, "edit profile -> my logins -> change password" doesn't seem that hard to find

Comment: @Glorfindel with SE's ever-ending "look" improvements, the screenshot seems to be out of date again

Answer (score 15):

It's changed again in 2019. You now have to go to https://meta.stackexchange.com/ and click your profile pic at the top right and click "Edit profile and settings" tab [image]

After that click "My logins" and from there you can change your password across all stack exchange websites. As of October 2019 this is the new and only way.

[image]

Comment: Thankfully this works, but knowing StackExchange UX it'll be deprecated in 2 weeks. **NOTE**  if one doesn't see the "change password" link, try adding a new login and then removing the previous one, changing password on new login.

Answer (score 5):

The 2011 and 2014 and 2018 did not work for me.
So latest from 2019 :)

**New from 2019**

This worked for me -

Login in any of your sites such as stackoverflow.com or meta.stackexchange.com or anysite linked to stackexchange.

Then change the browser url to https://meta.stackexchange.com

Then click on your profile pic on the right hand side and then click my_logins. You will see the following screen -

[image]

Now click on **My logins**

---

**Old from 2018:**
Login in any of your sites such as stackoverflow.com or meta.stackexchange.com or anysite linked to stackexchange.

Then change the browser url to https://stackexchange.com

Then click on your profile pic on the right hand side and then click my_logins. You will see the following screen -

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The "my logins" link can be found here:

[image: my logins link]

After clicking it follow Michaels answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't remember your old password, it appears you can go to account recovery, and request an email reset there, commonly called the forgot password form

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery

Comment: This is the only answer that helped me change my password!

Comment: You can effectively change your email address using this method as well:
1. Use the [Add more logins...] button to add your new email to a StackExchange site you are already logged in at.
2. Enter your new email into https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery
3. Click the "set a password here" link in your "Account Recovery - Meta Stack Exchange" email":
This email [has] no password ... associated with it yet....  
If you initiated this request, set a password here.
4. Re-log into the StackExchange site and you should see your new email address added.
5. Remove old.