# Changing password?

Tags: support, password

I would like to change my password.

I have followed the instructions in [How do I change my Stack Exchange password?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104206/how-do-i-change-my-stack-exchange-password) but I cannot find the "my logins" hyperlink.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your [My Logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) is under the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab of your profile:

[image: my logins]