# My logins page is blank

Tags: bug, login, stack-exchange-openid

I wanted to remove my facebook login since my facebook profile doesn't exist anymore, and so I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) to remove the login.

However, when I confirmed I wanted to delete the login, it removed *all* of them from the page, including my stackexchange one. So now, it looks like this:

[image: from stackexchange.com]

And like this:

[image: from my meta profile]

I then got really worried that I wouldn't be able to log in again, so I added my google account just to be safe, and both came back:

[image: with google account]

Then, because I wanted to see if I could re-create this bug, I tried to remove my google account, and magically *both* disappeared at the same time. I've repeated this process a couple of times while making this ticket (adding and removing my google account, to see if the stackexchange one follows), and every time, removing my google account also removes the stackexchange line.

So then, with the logins page blank, to see if my email address was still somewhere, I went though the password recovery process [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and I got this in an email.

[image: Email]

Phew! So even though the stackexchange login isn't being displayed, it is still associated with me somewhere because I get the password reset email.

However, I don't want to have a google account associated with my stackexchange login.

I am concerned that:
1) I won't be able to change my stackexchange password (the instructions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104206/how-do-i-change-my-stack-exchange-password) don't work when the page is blank)
2) I won't be able to log in again if I log myself out.

Even though it seems I still have a stackexchange login, it is disconcerting to not be able to see it or change my password anymore. It seems like there is a bug where my login is not displayed, but I don't know if it's just a display issue, or has actually been taken away in some other partial fashion.

Also, in case it's relevant, both the email addresses are the same. The stackexchange gmail login and the gmail id login were both the same in this case.

I'm going to try a couple more things:

1) try a different gmail account and see if that breaks too,
2) try and log out and log in again. If I can't get in again then I'll fill in the password recovery form and hope for the best.

Different gmail account:

The plot thickens. Now, I added a different gmail account and STILL didn't get the stackexchange login back:

[image: other gmail]

So it seems that even adding a gmail account doesn't help get my stackexchange credentials back. I removed this other gmail account and the logins page is blank again.

Log out and in again:

So with the logins page blank, I was still able to use my stackexchange credentials to log in.

Different stackexchange account:

I also happen to have a second stackexchange account (I've been super-duper careful not to overlap the two, I promise! I can give details of both if needed!) and I tried this with my other account, and that one also did the same thing. Now BOTH are blank. So, it should be easy to re-create this issue since it seems like it's not just my one account.

Comment: You can test whether you can log in or not by opening an private/incognito browser window. SE allows multiple simultaneous logins.